# Adding a signature in QGIS with Input-App

Tags: qgis, qfield, mergin-maps

I'm working on an formular for checking different things (eg. broken trees). Is it possible to add a signature from the smartphone/tablet? Using the input-app (or qfield), complete the form an in the end write your signature with the finger in your smartphone and store it in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible yet in the Input app.

As a work-around, users can attach their signatures as a photo to the form.

I hope this helps.